# Adding XML element in XML file using sed command in shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

I am using sed command to insert an xml element into the existing xml file.

I have xml file as

```
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```

I want to add new elememt as

```
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student>
```

So my new xml file will be

```
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```

For this I have written shell script as

```
#! /bin/bash

CONTENT="<student>
            <name>NewName</name>
            <id>NewID</id>
        </student>"

#sed -i.bak '/<\/Students>/ i \ "$CONTENT" /root/1.xml
sed -i.bak '/<\/Students>/ i \'$CONTENT'/' /root/1.xml
```

I am getting error as

```
sed: can't read <name>NewName</name>: No such file or directory
sed: can't read <id>NewID</id>: No such file or directory
sed: can't read </student>: No such file or directory
```

And in the xml file, only `<student>` is added.
The remaining elements are not added.
Does anyone know why this error?

Comment: Several tools exist to manipulate XML files.  Use those instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @devnull would be nice of you to list one (or two) of those tools

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change this:

```
CONTENT="<student>
            <name>NewName</name>
            <id>NewID</id>
        </student>"
```

to this:

```
CONTENT="<student>\n<name>NewName</name>\n<id>NewID</id>\n</student>"
```

and then:

```
C=$(echo $CONTENT | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
sed "/<\/Students>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" file
```

Comment: If my tag is <name>New Name</name>, then how can handle whitespace here?  '\t' will add one tab and I need single whitespace

Comment: @USer007 You can escape the space character with backslash-space

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have an unescaped newline in sed replacement text, that is `$CONTENT` in your example. sed uses the newline just like the shell does, to terminate a command.

If you need a newline in the replacement text, you need to precede it with a backslash.

There is another way to add text using the `r` option. For example:

Lets say your main file is;

```
$ cat file
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```

You text you want to add is in another file (not variable):

```
$ cat add.txt
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student>
```

You can do (using `gnu sed`):

```
$ sed '/<\/Students>/{ 
    r add.txt
    a \</Students>
    d 
}' file
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```

However, having given this option, it is still a very bad idea to parse xml with regular expression. It makes the solution very fragile and easy to break. Consider this as a learning exercise only.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
CONTENT='    <student>\
    <name>NewName</name>\
    <id>NewID</id>\
</student>'

sed '/<\/Students>/i\'"$CONTENT" file
```

Alternatively, put the new students in a file and:

```
sed '/<\/Students>/e cat new_student_file' file
```

Comment: Here if tag is like <name>New Name</name>, then how can I handle this whitespace.

Comment: @Optimus for the variable just remember that the last character of each line (but the last) must end in `\\`. For the file solution just write the text as you see it.