# Unable to add new tags in xml using sed in linux shell

Tags: regex, xml, shell, maven, sed

I am trying to add an xml element in my "pom.xml" file at a particular place, i have tried as the answer mentioned in the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-uisng-sed-command-in-shell-script) question. But still it is not working.. 
I do not understand REGEX , so i am having trouble figuring out the problem.

I have to add following xml element between the "properties" and "dependencies" tag.

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://your.server.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

**"pom.xml (Before)"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Component</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <properties>
  ....
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.proxy-service</groupId>
      <artifactId>Handler</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </project>
```

**pom.xml(After)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Component</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <properties>
  ....
  </properties>
  <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://your.server.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.proxy-service</groupId>
      <artifactId>Handler</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </project>
```

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh

# First Script



CONTENT="<distributionManagement>\n<repository>\n<id>deployment</id>\n</repository>\n</distributionManagement>"



echo "Start"

C=$(echo $CONTENT | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
sed "/<\/project>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" *pom.xml*



echo "finish"
```

**Error i am getting:**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command
```

Please help me that if i am following the right command or approach. If there is another command that will do the job but it should be supported both in "**Ubuntu**" and "**Redhat**".

Comment: You should consider using a parent pom file instead of adding that bit to every single pom file in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTENT="  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>deployment</id>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>"

awk -v content="$CONTENT" '{ print $0 } /<\/properties>/ { print content }' pom.xml
```

This instructs awk to print all lines, and additionally print `content` (here set to `"$CONTENT"`) if the current line matches `</properties>`. Generally, I find that if you're tempted to substitute shell variables into sed commands, it's worth considering awk instead. Others will probably disagree.