# Replace multiple lines using sed with other multiple lines

Tags: sed

I am trying to find these two lines:

```
  <paramsToUseForLimit></paramsToUseForLimit>
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>
```

and replace them with:

```
  <paramsToUseForLimit/>
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>
<jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl plugin="branch-api@2.6.3">
  <durationName>hour</durationName>
  <count>2</count>
  <userBoost>false</userBoost>
</jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl>
```

from my file config.json

Can someone help me to do this with sed ?

sed -ie "s/Those two lines/Replaced with those 7 lines/g" /config.json

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question, but this is not clear; could you please post more clear samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, i have edited the comment

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4265352) should put you on the right track.

Comment: Do not use `sed` to parse xml files. Use `xmlstarlet` to insert data in xml. Also `sed` works with _lines_. Doing multiline replces in `sed` is _hard_. It's _not_ the tool for the job

Comment: the solution that worked for me i found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-using-sed-command-in-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

sed may not be the best tool for this task.

```
sed -ie '/^  <\(paramsToUseForLimit>\)<\/\1/{
  N
  /\n<\/hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>/{
    i \
  <paramsToUseForLimit/>\
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>\
<jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl plugin="branch-api@2.6.3">\
  <durationName>hour</durationName>\
  <count>2</count>\
  <userBoost>false</userBoost>\
</jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl>
    d
  }
}' /config.json
```

- `/^.../{` - if pattern space matches first match line:

  - `N` - append next line of input to pattern space
  - `/\n.../{` - if pattern space matches second match line:

    - `i \` - insert new text (`\` before embedded newlines)
    - `d`- delete original text, implicit print, and start next cycle
- otherwise, implicit print (two lines if `N` ran, else one line)
- start next cycle

This is quite fragile. For example, watch out for shell metacharacters in the inserted text.

Comment: Perhaps the `c` over the `i` command? Both have to use the backslash to continue their input over a newline which points to using a less error fraught technique by using the `r file` having already copied the replacement lines into a second file. e.g. `sed -e  '/pattern/{r replacementFile' -e 'd}' inputFile`

Comment: @potong nice! That's much cleaner. Only issue is `pattern` is multiline, so perhaps still need to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed with `-z` option and inspired with [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) question and answer - you can properly escape the patterns and replace newlines with `\` `n` characters and then pass to sed. Then it's simple:

```
KEYWORD='  <paramsToUseForLimit></paramsToUseForLimit>
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>'
REPLACE='  <paramsToUseForLimit/>
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>
<jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl plugin="branch-api@2.6.3">
  <durationName>hour</durationName>
  <count>2</count>
  <userBoost>false</userBoost>
</jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty_-JobPropertyImpl>'
ESCAPED_KEYWORD=$(printf '%s\n' "$KEYWORD" | sed -z 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g; s/\n/\\n/g');
ESCAPED_REPLACE=$(printf '%s\n' "$REPLACE" | sed -z 's/[\/&]/\\&/g; s/\n/\\n/g')
sed -z "s/$ESCAPED_KEYWORD/$ESCAPED_REPLACE/" input_file.txt
```